# comment lines only with specific path

Tags: text-processing

I have file which has the lines like below..

```
/opt/appdyn
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/upgradeExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/IBMWebsphereMQExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/certs
```

I wanted to comment only the lines are `/opt/appdyn` and `/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension`.

The expected out put would be

```
#/opt/appdyn
#/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/upgradeExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/IBMWebsphereMQExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/certs
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To comment out these lines, you could use `sed`.  The only trick is you also need to include the end-of-line character `$` or you'll affect the other lines:

```
$ cat file
/opt/appdyn
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/upgradeExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/IBMWebsphereMQExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/certs
$ sed -e 's|/opt/appdyn$|#/opt/appdyn|' -i file
$ sed -e 's|/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension$|#/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension|' -i file
$ cat file
#/opt/appdyn
#/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/upgradeExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/configscripts/IBMWebsphereMQExt.sh
/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension/wmqmonitor-7.0.4/certs
```

Comment: Wow!! small trick helps me a lot :)

Comment: Do consider using a different delimiter, so that you have a more readable expression: `s|/opt/appdyn$|#/opt/appdyn/|`.

Comment: Good point, that *is* nicer

Comment: But some times $ is omitting..the forming the script as s|/opt/appdyn#/opt/appdyn/| and then failing

Comment: sed -i -e 's~/opt/appdyn#/opt/appdyn~' pkg/package.spec
sed: -e expression #1, char 26: unterminated `s' command
make: *** [buildpackage] Error 1

Comment: You wrote `s|/opt/appdyn#/opt/appdyn/|` but should have written `s|/opt/appdyn|#opt/appdyn|`.   You missed a `|` in the middle.

Comment: The `'s'` sed expression needs three pipes:  `s|find|replace|`

Comment: No I have not missed that......During the runtime it seems to me, it considering $| as variable to the script and then returning with empty

Comment: $(SED) -i -e 's~/opt/appdyn$~#/opt/appdyn~' pkg/package.spec
        $(SED) -i -e 's~/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension$~#/opt/appdyn/AppdExtension~' pkg/package.spec
 my example code

Comment: when i run this command manually it is working..... But when I run it in the make file getting this issue.

Comment: Please use ` around code blocks so we can read it easier.  It looks like you are using tilda which should be fine.  What shell are you using.  With things encapsulated in ' it shouldn't do any substitution.  You can try escaping $ as \$, but $ is a regex character for "end of line".  Did you try this in a stand-alone directory?  I tested what I wrote in the answer ok in bash, so I suspect its a difference in shell or in the surrounding environment.

Comment: used another tric and got worked.. `$(SED) -i -e 's|/opt/appdyn$$|#|' pkg/package.spec`